# Prepopulate complex form values in rails edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have an assessment form that renders a list of questions, and accepts answers for each question. The form data is submitted manually via ajax.

I'm having an issue when trying to pre-populate the data in my edit view. Here's how my views look:

edit.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
    <%= render 'assessment_form', :locals=> {:assessment => @assessment} %>
</div>
```

_assessment_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @assessment do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit 'Save', :class=> "btn btn-primary", :style=>"width: 100%;" %>

      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-10">
        <h4>Show on Followup?</h4>
     </div>

      <% @assessment.questions.where(category:"S").each do |question| %>
        <%= render 'question_fields', :question=> question, :f=> f %>
      <% end %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, :value=> @assessment.patient.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :template_id, :value=> @assessment.template_id %>
<% end %>
```

_question_fields.html.erb:

```
<p><%= question.content %></p>

  <%= f.fields_for :answer do |builder| %>

    <div class="row question">

      <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right toggle">
        <%= builder.check_box :tracking, {:checked=> false, :class=>"trackable", :data => {:'on-text' => "Yes", :'off-text' => "No", :'on-color'=> "success", :question => question.id}}, 0 , 1 %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <%= builder.text_area :content, :class=>"form-control question-field", :data => {:question => question.id} %>
       </div>

    </div>

  <% end %>
```

But none of the answers content are rendering in the view, the form fields are blank.

Here's an example call: Assessment.last.answers.first.content  will give me the string "test". That should be showing up in my text_area box but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Just do, the instance variable @assessment is passed to the partial.

```
<%= render 'assessment_form' %>
```

Comment: Are you sure question.content has a value? Your example is getting Answer.content, not question.

Comment: So the question.content is a fixed value from a table, and it's rendering fine in the view (this is the actual "question" e.g. "What is your height?").   But the f.fields_for :answer form is not rendering any of the answers to those questions, e,g, "test" .

Comment: The Assessment model has_many answers by the looks of your code, your fields_for :answer doesn't hit anything. You did not provide your model info  in the question, but I think you should be reaching the answers via the question instead of Assessment, so depending on the logic it would either be `f.fields_for @question.answer`

Comment: Right - Originally a question did have_many answers but I realized it actually makes sense for answers to belong to assessments. But f.fields_For @assessment.answers   throws undefined method `content' for #<Answer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fdb1207a0b8>

Comment: That's because you can only call that method for a single question. '@assessment.answers.map(&:content)' will get the content for each question.